# How to retry kotlin channel trySend when ChannelResult is channelResult = Value(Failed)

Tags: android, kotlin, channel

My current Android application employs an actor:-

```
private val _reactions = MutableSharedFlow<Reaction>(replay = 0, extraBufferCapacity = 3, onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST)
val reactions: SharedFlow<Reaction> = _reactions

private val actor = scope.actor<Action> {
    channel.consumeEach { action ->
        _reactions.tryEmit(reduce(action = action))
    }
}
```

Messages are sent via this method:-

```
fun send(action: Action) {
    val channelResult = actor.trySend(action)
}
```

I have an intermittent error condition, where the very first call to `send(action: Action)`, when the Application opens "Cold", results in a ChannelResult = Failed as shown by these logcat logs

```
2021-10-13 13:42:58.184 7291-7291: channelResult = Value(Failed)
2021-10-13 13:42:58.184 7291-7291: channelResult isClosed = false
2021-10-13 13:42:58.184 7291-7291: channelResult isFailure = true
2021-10-13 13:42:58.185 7291-7291: channelResult isSuccess = false
```

In these cases I would like to automatically retry (With a backoff)
I cannot see any related methods to support this approach though

How can I code a retry of my trySend call?

Comment: I don't put this as an answer, because I'm not sure if it fixes the problem, but try to enable buffering in actor: `actor = scope.actor<Action>(capacity = Channel.UNLIMITED) {`. Without buffering `trySend()` will always occasionally fail, e.g. when invoked in quick succession.

Comment: @broot, nice catch, I think that fixes my issue